# Как упростить данное условие в языке Golang?

Tags: golang

У меня есть объект, который выглядит так:

```
type Message struct {
    Actions        []Action       `json:"actions"`
    Keyboards       []Keyboard     `json:"keyboards"`
}

var response Message
```

actions выглядит так: `[{"name":"test", "users": [1, 2]}, {"name":"!kick", "users": [101]}]`, actions может быть и пустым, подобное и с Keyboards

Сейчас код выглядит так:

```
if len(response.Actions) > 0 && len(response.Actions[0].Users) > 0 && response.Actions[0].Users == 1 {
    ...
}
```

Что можно сделать, чтобы обойтись без len?

Comment: Добавь метод для структуры Message, и вызывай его. Типа `func (m Message) isValid() bool { вагон условий }`. Так вся суета с len и прочим будет спрятана от клиентского кода.

Comment: если берешь len от `response.Actions[0].Users`, то это массив. а дальше значение сравниваешь с единицей. тут где-то ошибка.